# What's the truth table of this circuit

Tags: logic, circuit, truthtable, circuit-diagram

I'm trying to make a truth table of this electronic circuit:

[image]

How does this work? How can I know what the value of B is for example A = 0 and C = 0? Isn't this an infinite recursive structure? Or how does that work? I used Logism to simulate the circuit and found this truth table:

```
A = 0 C = 0 --> B = 1
A = 1 C = 0 --> B = 1
A = 0 C = 1 --> B = 1
A = 1 C = 1 --> B = 0
```

Now, is this correct? And what's the boolean expression for this circuit given A and C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if C=1 -> the multiplexer select the A input, and then B=NOT(A)

if C=0 the multiplexer select the NOT(B) input and then, B=NOT(NOT(B))=B. or the last value of not(A) just in the edge from 1 to 0 of C.

if C=0 -> B holds your value. Whatever it is 0 or 1.

So, if C=1 --> B=NOT(A) whatever is the A value. it is live a Flip Flip D, not Master-Slave, With D=A and B=not(Q). C=Clock

If C=0 B is hold in the last value, Like a Flip Flop NOT master-slave said before.

The truth table is:

A    C    B

0    0    B

0    1    1

1    0    B

1    1    0

Note that with C=1, B=not(A), and with C=0, B=not(not(B))=B, that show B holds the value it has. the NOT(A) just when C change from 1 to 0.

It is a single Flip Flop D.
Not Master-Slave, A=D, B=NOT(Q), C=Clock